# how to properly use a protocol that has an associated type to describe a property in another object

Tags: swift, generics, swift-protocols

I have been creating a SwiftUI component, and I want this component to have a property that implements a protocol. The specific use case is drawing an Axis for a chart, which is based on a scale.

There are several concrete implementations of the scale that transform data from an input domain to an output range. The two I'm starting with is a Linear scale that converts from an `Double` input domain to an output range represented with a `Double`. The other is a Date/Time based scale that converted from a `Date` based input domain to an output range represented by a `Double`.

Scale is the protocol, and I took a stab at roughly defining it as:

```swift
public protocol Scale {
    associatedtype InputDomain: Comparable // input domain

    var isClamped: Bool { get }

    // input values
    var domain: ClosedRange<InputDomain> { get }

    // output values
    var range: ClosedRange<Double> { get }

    /// converts a value between the input "domain" and output "range"
    ///
    /// - Parameter inputValue: a value within the bounds of the ClosedRange for domain
    /// - Returns: a value within the bounds of the ClosedRange for range, or NaN if it maps outside the bounds
    func scale(_ inputValue: InputDomain) -> Double

    /// converts back from the output "range" to a value within the input "domain". The inverse of scale()
    ///
    /// - Parameter outputValue: a value within the bounds of the ClosedRange for range
    /// - Returns: a value within the bounds of the ClosedRange for domain, or NaN if it maps outside the bounds
    func invert(_ outputValue: Double) -> InputDomain

    /// returns an array of the locations within the ClosedRange of range to locate ticks for the scale
    ///
    /// - Parameter count: a number of ticks to display, defaulting to 10
    /// - Returns: an Array of the values within the ClosedRange of the input range
    func ticks(count: Int) -> [InputDomain]
}
```

The LinearScale and TimeScale structs conform the the protocol, each defining a `typealias InputDomain = Double` and `typealias InputDomain = Date` respectively.

The issue comes when I try to use this protocol to describe the kind of struct (a scale) that is used more generically with the SwiftUI component:

```swift
public struct AxisView: View {    
    let scale:  Scale

    public var body: some View { ... }
}
```

The compiler provides the error:
`Protocol 'Scale' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements`

I'm not sure of the best way to tackle this problem, to resolve the compiler error/constraints. Should I be doing something to make the SwiftUI component a generic, or should I be not using an associated type with the protocol?

Or is there another way to think about structuring this code to support a variety of scale types, using protocols and structs?

**UPDATE**: I got an answer to the original question, but it's not entirely gelling for me. I added the generic definition to the enclosing type (my implementations of `Scale`).

What I'm not clear on is why this is needed? After I added the generic marker on the enclosing struct, the compiler error went away. I'm assuming this is a place where there were several options that the swift compiler could have taken, and telling it "yeah, I want this to be a generic" is one path - what are possible other ones?

I also noticed that even though it was defined as a generic class, the specific class that I used was often inferred by the swift compiler. So I didn't need to fully specify the type with the generic syntax. For example, I could use

`LinearScale()` instead of `LinearScale<Double>`(), and it would infer the correct generic. Is that expected?

Comment: It's kind of bad style but you could declare scale as an `Any` and unwrap it where necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should make your view generic as well:

```
public struct AxisView<ScaleType: Scale>: View {    
    let scale:  ScaleType    
    public var body: some View { ... }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the pointer in the right direction - I've updated the question a bit, as I'm not entirely certainly what's happening when I make the view Generic as well. The compiler appears to infer quite a bit around that, so why couldn't it infer I needed a generic struct as well? Was there another choice or pattern available here that I'm missing?

Comment: @heckj the swift compiler could be designed to suggest a change like that, but the designers didn’t do so, probably because it’s quite hard work and doesn’t bring much benefit. On the other hand, if you meant that swift should leave this code alone and just “assume” that you actually meant to make AxisView generic, then I think this is taking it too far. You don’t need `<Double>` because you already said what `InputDomain` is in `LinearScale`’s declaration.